# Stop perl overloading or print memory "address" of reference

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, memory-address

I have a class I created that overloads the `""` operator to print out a nice stringified form of the object that is user-readable.

But now, I'd like to actually get the memory address such as:

```
Some_class=HASH(0xb0aff98)
```

which is what I would have normally done by using `print "$some_object"` if I had not already overridden the `""` operator.

Is there someway to bypass the overridden method or, failing that, just get the memory address of this object?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#%24addr-%3d-refaddr(-%24ref-)

Comment: Overloading `""` and accessing the memory address of a variable sounds like a Bad Idea (tm).

Comment: @TLP, There are times you need an object's identity (e.g. inside-out objects), but I agree, that's rarely needed, except maybe for debugging when you have multiple objects that stringify to the same thing.

Comment: Using `qq()` would be an alternative to `"`

Comment: Also, `print $some_object` is identical to `print "$some_object"` (except for the overloading, of course). You never have to put quotes around bare scalars.

Comment: @ikegami Like I said, it sounds like a bad idea. A Perl novice is more likely to have an XY-problem on his hands than need to use some obscure technique.

Comment: @TLP, Like I said, I agree. :)

Comment: Yes, this was for debugging purposes. I wanted to make sure I wasn't using another copy of an object. I was using the memory address to confirm two references pointed to the same object.

Comment: Like I said, an XY-problem. References are numerical, so you can just do a straight comparison: `if ($obj1 == $obj2)`.

Comment: Well, the location of `$obj2` was deep in my code. Wasn't going to be easy to pass `$obj1` to there. Easier was to just print to `STDOUT` the stringified memory address and compare myself.

Comment: @EMiller I do not agree with that arbitrary limitation. Distance has no meaning in Perl code. If you use a global variable you can access it anywhere in your code.

Comment: I try to avoid global variables as I find it hard to keep track of who has modified such variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`overload::StrVal($o)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Public-Functions).

```
use overload '""' => sub { "Hello, World!" };
my $o = bless({});
print($o, "\n");                     # Hello, World!
print(overload::StrVal($o), "\n");   # main=HASH(0x62d038)
```

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

1. Use [`overload::StrVal`](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#Public-Functions)

   > #### Public Functions
   >
   > Package `overload.pm` provides the following public functions:
   >
   > - `overload::StrVal(arg)`
   >
   >   Gives the string value of `arg` as in the absence of stringify overloading. If you are using this to get the address of a reference (useful for checking if two references point to the same thing) then you may be better off using `Scalar::Util::refaddr()` , which is faster.
2. Use [`Scalar::Util::refaddr()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#%24addr-%3d-refaddr(-%24ref-))

   > #### `$addr = refaddr( $ref )`
   >
   > If `$ref` is reference the internal memory address of the referenced value is returned as a plain integer. Otherwise undef is returned.
   >
   > ```
   >    1.    $addr = refaddr "string";           # undef
   >    2.    $addr = refaddr \$var;              # eg 12345678
   >    3.    $addr = refaddr [];                 # eg 23456784
   >    4. 
   >    5.    $obj  = bless {}, "Foo";
   >    6.    $addr = refaddr $obj;               # eg 88123488
   > ```