# Where is Perl's default object-to-string conversion defined?

Tags: perl, operator-overloading

If I print a reference to a blessed object in Perl, I get something like this:

```
Foo::Bar=HASH(0x0123456789ab)
```

Where is that code defined? The first part is `ref($obj)`, but where does the HASH hex value come from?

I'm attempting to write a `to_string` overloaded operator for objects that have an optional `name` attribute. If the `name` is provided, I'd like it to print

```
Foo::Bar(name=joe)
```

and fall back to the default Perl string if not `name` is undefined. So I either have to be able to invoke Perl's conversion code from my code, or write the equivalent myself, hence my question.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe the format is documented, but it's unlikely to change. It's equivalent to

```
use Scalar::Util qw( blessed refaddr reftype );

my $pkg = blessed($ref);
my $str = sprintf("%s%s(0x%x)",
   ( defined($pkg) ? "$pkg=" : "" ),
   reftype($ref),
   refaddr($ref),
);
```

You can use `blessed`, `reftype` and `refaddr` if you want the components of Perl's stringification of a reference, but the following is the best way to obtain Perl's stringification of a reference:

```
use overload qw( );

my $str = overload::StrVal($ref);
```

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, of course the minute after I post this, I find the answer:

```
overload::StrVal($o)
```

(see also [Stop perl overloading or print memory "address" of reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126621/stop-perl-overloading-or-print-memory-address-of-reference#26126887))

Answer (score 2):

One way to stringify an object based on object's data (attributes)

```
package ClassStringify;

use warnings;
use strict;

sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_; 
    return bless { %args }, $class; 
}

use overload  q("") => sub { 
    my $self = shift; 
    return exists $self->{name} ? $self->stringify() : $self;
};

sub stringify {
    my $self = shift;
    return join "\n", map { "$_ => $self->{$_}" } keys %$self;
}

1;
```

with main

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use ClassStringify;

say ClassStringify->new( name => 'obj_name', id => 123 );
say '---';    
say ClassStringify->new( id => 123 );
```

what prints

```
name => obj_name
id => 123
---
ClassStringify=HASH(0x23b62c8)
```

---

For the desired print format

```
use overload  q("") => sub { 
    my $self = shift; 
    return exists $self->{name} ? $self->stringify('name') : $self;   
};

sub stringify {
    my ($self, $attr) = @_; 
    return ref($self) . " ($attr=$self->{$attr})";
}
```

This prints

```
ClassStringify (name=obj_name)
---
ClassStringify=HASH(0x22852c8)
```